# How to harden RDP with SSH from Linux to Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, ubuntu, openssh, remote-desktop

I need help and a step-by-step guide how to setup SSH tunneled RDP from my Ubuntu (18.04) laptop to my Windows 10 desktop both across LAN and WAN. I have a hunch what to do in theory, but not in practice. I would prefer to use any FOSS solutions if possible.

I have OpenSSH server installed in my Windows 10 and in Ubuntu I could use e.g. Remmina as RDP/SSH client. Remmina seems to have SSH functionality also included. While installing OpenSSH server in Windows and following Microsoft's guide found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement

I encountered problem when trying to execute the following command:
Install-Module -Force OpenSSHUtils -Scope AllUsers

Command fails with the following error code:
The module 'OpenSSHUtils' cannot be installed or updated because the authenticode signature of the file 'OpenSSHUtils.psd1' is not valid.

While trying to troubleshoot this via Google I found out that it indicates that Windows OpenSSHUtils is deprecated. If there is no valid OpenSSHUtils or I can't continue with Windows OpenSSH server, then I don't mind using other SSH server solutions.

I've been using and satisfied with Bitvise SSH server/client solution found in Windows only, but haven't found any cross-platform solution yet. I would be very grateful for any found recommendation or solution, especially if they are FOSS. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Isn't it possible to establish ssh with TCP tunnel first then use RDP client to connect to windows? I mean, the standard approach as we are using for years... ssh -L 3389:localhost:3389 username@machine then use rdp client to connect to local 3389 port?

Comment: By the way, I think it is not security related question, its more administrative one.

Comment: Fis was correct, you can port forward through SSH, and then just connect to yourself on that port. It will use the tunnel and push to the port on the remote machine. It's that easy.

Comment: This question probably belongs to super user forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by myself and this is how I did it:

1. First generate SSH public key with your Linux (see e.g. this https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-1804/)
2. Install OpenSSH server into Windows and set it to start automatically (optionally set authentication method public key only + passphrase, but no password). Forget crappy Microsoft instructions and follow e.g. this video guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCtdkr6FfLU
3. Restart OpenSSH server in Windows and save your public key generated in step 1 into Windows OpenSSH server. See the same video guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCtdkr6FfLU
4. Use Remmina in Linux and set appropriate RDP + SSH settings (use your public key generated in step 1)